# Using while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) to display images from database but only 1 image is shown

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop

I try to fetch all image from database but only one image is shown.
this is my code:

```
     <?php

     $query = "SELECT id, name, image, price FROM products ORDER BY name";

     $stmt = $con-> prepare ( $query );

     $stmt->execute();

     $num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0){ 

//some html code
```

this is my while loop:

```
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        extract($row);
        echo "<div class='inner'>";         
        //creating new table row per record
            echo "<ul>";
                echo "<li>";
                    echo "<a class='thumb' href='images/{$image}'>";
                    echo "<div class='product-id' style='display:none;'>{$id}</div>";
                    echo "<span class='hoodnamecarousel'>{$name}</span>";
                    echo"</a>";
                echo "</li>";
            echo "</ul>";           
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
```

This is second part of displaying image after click on any image:

```
    echo "<div id='thumbs2' style='display:none;'>";
        echo "<div class='inner'>";         
            echo "<ul>";
                echo "<li>";
                    echo "<a class='thumb' href='images/{$image}'></a>";
                    echo "<div class='product-id' style='display:none;'>{$id}</div>";
                    echo "<span class='hoodnamecarousel'>{$name}</span>";
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo "<span class='price'>{$price}</span>";
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo "<a href='add_to_cart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}' class='button btn btn-primary'>";
                    echo "افزودن به سبد <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span>";
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</li>";
            echo"</ul>";            
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div id='closeBtn'>بستن</div>";
        }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";  
}
else {
echo "محصولات در حال بروزرسانی می باشند.";
}   
?>
```

this code only display 1 image and doesn't show other images from database
please help me!

Comment: Do you know for sure that the images returned from the db are correct? It would be easier for someone to answer, if you boil down the problem more.

Comment: Check the sourcecode of the page if it contains the text for the missing images. It looks to me as if you just have too many `</div>` in your code and the browser just doesn't know where to show your images.